# Cómo enviar datos a un servicio en nueva ventana en Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular7

Espere me puedan ayudar, quisiera saber cómo puedo enviar datos por post a un servicio rest, en una nueva ventana en angular 2.
Tengo una tabla donde con un ngFor muestro todos, en caso de que no este pagado muestro un botón hacía la función pagar, como se ve a continuación:

```
                <tr *ngFor=" let pago of pagos">

                    <td>{{pago.descripcion}}</td>

                    <td>${{pago.monto}}</td>
                    <td>$ {{pago.recargos}}</td>
                    <td>${{pago.total}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button (click)="realizar_pago(pago)" >Pagar</button> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Lo que deseo haces es que en la función pagar de mi componente pueda enviar los datos del pago a través de post a un servicio web externo, no es necesario recibir una respuesta.
En mi componente.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
  realizar_pago ( pago: any ){
    this._pagoService.pagar(pago).subscribe(
      response =>{
          console.log(response);
      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Mi duda es cómo puedo realizar esto en el servicio, para poder enviar los datos de pago a una url especifica en otra ventana donde al recibir mis datos, los mostrará.

Espero haber sido claro, gracias

Comment: no entiendo muy bien quieres mostrar los datos que le envias al servicio POST en otra ventana?por ventana te refieres a modal?componente?

Comment: Necesito enviar pago con todo lo que contiene por post a un servicio web pero al mismo tiempo abrir eso en otra ventana para ver el resultado. Un ejemplo por get sería: var params = 'p='+pago.id_solicitud; window.open("https://www.google.com?"+params, "_blank"); donde la dirección de google sería la del servicio, esto es porque el servicio al recibir los datos los muestra.